# Android Problem with special character phone numbers and ACTION_CALL

Tags: android, phone-number

I found a problem which I can't find solution, maybe someone has seen this before?

I use this to perform a call, now if the call is a special number such as *111#, the character # is not sent to the activity, resulting in a call to *111 without the # character.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(intent);
```

Anyone understand what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should url-encode your `tel:*111#`:

```
String telUri = "tel:" + Uri.encode("*111#");
```